# Convenient flags handling where all flags cannot fit into 64-bit

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a convenient flags handler in C++.

The usual idea is to use something like this:

```
enum class Flag {
    Foo = 1<<0,
    Bar = 1<<1,
    Baz = 1<<2
};

// these operators can be generalized by using template functions with SFINAE
Flag operator|(Flag a, Flag b) {
    return static_cast<Flag>(static_cast<underlying_type>(a)|static_cast<underlying_type>(b));
}
// add other operators here, like &, ^, |=, etc.
```

This works, however I have two problems with this:

- `Flag` is used in a way that it doesn't necessarily store **a** flag, but several flags. It's not a big problem, but I don't consider this good design, because `Flag` now actually stores a value which is not listed as an enum-member. If I change operators' return value to underlying_type, then I loose information about that it stores flags of `Flag`
- It doesn't scale: if I have more than 64 flags, this solution doesn't work any more

A further requirement for this handler is to able to handle not just 1-bit flags, but several-bit-wide enumerations (with these, it is easy to reach the 64-bit limit), and I'd like to be in control how bits are distributed among the handler (I mean, for example, I'd like to use this handler to ease handling OS calls, where bits position are determined by the API).

What (convenient to use, optimal, general) solution exist for this problem?

Comment: [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Comment: are you really so much memory and time constrained that you have to store flags in single bits? can you really not just use an `enum class : short int`? also is a system that requires a set of 64 flags sane? those are 2^64 states your objects can be in -- is that amount of complexity really required?

Comment: @blue, yes, there can be scenarios, where 64 bits is not enough. It's rare, but there is. I'd like to have a solution which scale (i.e., I don't have to use a different solution, when there are more than 64 flags). Besides, as I've said, there can be enumerations among these flags, so it is not that hard to reach 64 bits. Look at some windows API calls, how many flags they have.

Comment: If it's not one bit, it's not really a flag anymore. And if you're going to store arbitrary- but fixed-length data, you are looking at an ordinary `struct`.

Comment: @MSalters: okay, we can call it something else, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @geza: No, I literally mean a `struct`. As in `struct fields { int flag1 : 1; int not_a_flag : 2 };`

Comment: Using enums as flags, which implies storing values that are not named enumerators, has always been supported in C and C++. That’s why the underlying type for an `enum` has to be able to hold all of the bits used in all of the enumerators.

Comment: @MSalters: that could be a solution, yes. I've two problems with that: I cannot get all bits in as an integer in the case of they fits into one (for passing to OS). The other, that I already have a enum. So, if I add another entry to the enum, I have to make modifications at two places: enum & struct.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::vector<bool>` to store flags as bits (it is implemented that way). If the size of bitfield is fixed - use `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. This is just a concept, a lot of functionality is missing (multi-bit flags, other operators, etc.), but can be easily added.

Here's an example of usage:

```
enum class Group1 {
    AttrA,
    AttrB,
    AttrC,
};

// count tells to Flags how many entries are there.
// no other boilerplate code is needed
constexpr int count(Group1) {
    return 3;
}

enum class Group2 {
    AttrA,
    AttrB,
};

constexpr int count(Group2) {
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    Flags<Group1, Group2> flags; // flags will have 5 used bits in it
    flags |= Group1::AttrA;
    flags |= Group1::AttrC;

    flags = Group2::AttrB|Group1::AttrA;
}
```

Here's the solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

namespace Private {

template <typename ...FLAGS>
struct FlagsSize;

template <typename FIRST, typename ...TAIL>
struct FlagsSize<FIRST, TAIL...> {
    static constexpr int value = count(FIRST()) + FlagsSize<TAIL...>::value;
};

template <>
struct FlagsSize<> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template <typename ELEMENT, typename ...FLAGS>
struct FlagOffset;

template <typename ELEMENT, typename ...FLAGS>
struct FlagOffset<ELEMENT, ELEMENT, FLAGS...> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template <typename ELEMENT, typename FIRST, typename ...TAIL>
struct FlagOffset<ELEMENT, FIRST, TAIL...> {
    static constexpr int value = count(FIRST()) + FlagOffset<ELEMENT, TAIL...>::value;
};

}

template <typename ...FLAGS>
class Flags {
    public:
        static const std::size_t size = Private::FlagsSize<FLAGS...>::value;
    private:
        std::uint8_t m_storage[(size+7)/8];
    public:
        Flags() {
            clearAll();
        }

        void clearAll() {
            for (std::size_t i=0; i<sizeof(m_storage); i++) {
                m_storage[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        bool get(int index) const {
            return m_storage[index>>3]&(1<<(index&7));
        }
        void set(int index, bool value = true) {
            if (value) {
                m_storage[index>>3] |= 1<<(index&7);
            } else {
                m_storage[index>>3] &= ~(1<<(index&7));
            }
        }

        template <typename FLAG, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAG>>>
        bool get(FLAG flag) const {
            return get(Private::FlagOffset<FLAG, FLAGS...>::value+static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<FLAG>>(flag));
        }
        template <typename FLAG, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAG>>>
        Flags<FLAG> get() const {
            Flags<FLAG> r;
            for (std::size_t i=0; i<count(FLAG()); i++) {
                r.set(static_cast<FLAG>(i), get(static_cast<FLAG>(i)));
            }
            return r;
        }

        template <typename FLAG, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAG>>>
        void set(FLAG flag, bool value) {
            set(Private::FlagOffset<FLAG, FLAGS...>::value+static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<FLAG>>(flag), value);
        }

        template <typename FLAG, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAG>>>
        Flags &operator|=(FLAG flag) {
            set(flag, true);
            return *this;
        }
        template <typename FLAG, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAG>>>
        Flags &operator|=(const Flags<FLAG> &flags) {
            for (std::size_t i=0; i<count(FLAG()); i++) {
                set(static_cast<FLAG>(i), flags.get(static_cast<FLAG>(i)));
            }
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename ...FLAG>
        Flags &operator=(const Flags<FLAG...> &flags) {
            clearAll();
            (operator|=(flags.template get<FLAG>()), ...);
            return *this;
        }
};

template <typename FLAG, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAG>>>
constexpr Flags<FLAG> operator|(FLAG a, FLAG b) {
    Flags<FLAG> f;
    f |= a;
    f |= b;
    return f;
}

template <typename FLAGA, typename FLAGB, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<FLAGA>&&std::is_enum_v<FLAGB>>>
constexpr Flags<FLAGA, FLAGB> operator|(FLAGA a, FLAGB b) {
    Flags<FLAGA, FLAGB> f;
    f |= a;
    f |= b;
    return f;
}
```